# Is it possible to change the color of the letter navigation in IOS 7 PeoplePicker?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, peoplepicker

Is it possible to change the color of the letter navigation in IOS 7 PeoplePicker and also the tintColor (I believe) inside, when one chooses a Contact from the Picker to see it's details. We're trying to move to Orange as you can see in the top bar.

Here are two images to better show what I'm talking about.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Hope you guys can help and thank you in advance.

Comment: i hope there no built in but you can achieve customize picker plenty of code on outside

Comment: Sorry mate I could not understand your response. :/

Comment: did you use ABPeoplePicker is it right?

Comment: Yes I did. Are you saying we should customize the color picker code?

Comment: No. you have do with custom peoplepicker

Comment: Do you have any links or something that would help with that?